# Setting location of site on nginx

Tags: centos, nginx

I have a pretty simple problem that I can't solve. I've been searching the web for some time but no good results.

I would like to change the default location of the site on my nginx server running on CentOS.

Location of my site folder is html.

I've edited the nginx.conf file so it looks like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8kp9plpnucos41/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-12%20at%201.37.10%20PM.png) is the folder structure of server.

Server was restated afterwards.

When if enter IP address of server I'm still getting nginx default html page.

Any idea what can be the solution?

If I missed some needed info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `root` to an absolute path and `html` doesn't look like one.

ex.

`location / {
    root /root/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}`

and ensure the correct permissions.

Comment: It also is a good idea to [put `root` within `server`](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls), and not within `location`.

Comment: You mean /root/nginx-1.6.0/html? I've tried that but no luck. I even deleted the default index.html from the server and replace this file with my test one, and it's still showing the deleted page. very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Add `default_server` to the `listen` directive:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```